# How to get user account info in code with Windows Authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight-4.0

If WebApp is configured as Windows Authentication, how to get the user credential in code?
How to create NetworkCredential using this exsiting user credential?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you mean User.Identity?

Comment: I want to get current user credential to call a web service or access another website.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

> The DefaultCredentials property
>   applies only to NTLM, negotiate, and
>   Kerberos-based authentication.
>
> DefaultCredentials represents the
>   system credentials for the current
>   security context in which the
>   application is running. For a
>   client-side application, these are
>   usually the Windows credentials (user
>   name, password, and domain) of the
>   user running the application. For
>   ASP.NET applications, the default
>   credentials are the user credentials
>   of the logged-in user, or the user
>   being impersonated.

**Example:**

```
 System.Net.WebProxy proxyObject = new System.Net.WebProxy();
 proxyObject.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Comment: System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredential is not available for silverlight 4 even adding reference for System.Net. Maybe this assessment has different version for silverlight sandbox.

Comment: You should put those details in your question, you only have ASP.NET tagged.